# Adding attribute containing an illegal character @ to DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

**Context**

I am in a situation in which I want to re-render some existing HTML using javascript. The server side is not under my control, I cannot apply any changes to the HTML document I am working on, I have to work fully client-side.

I would like to leverage vue functionality, using [`petite-vue`](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue). In order to do that, I plan to manipulate the DOM and add the vue directives to the DOM nodes in a preparation script. After that script is done, I want to mount the `vue` application.

**Question**

One problem with this approach is that some `vue` directives have illegal characters. For instance, on a certain element, I want to set an attribute `Attr("@vue:mounted", "mounted()")`. This raises a `DOMException`, because `@vue:mounted` [is not a valid XML-Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-name) (due to the starting `@`) which is a requirement for DOM attribute names.

How can I set this attribute so that `vue` is going to accept it? I think that `vue` somehow works around the illegal character, as it somehow manages to read the attribute. But I am not familiar with the internals of `vue`. Maybe there is also an way to achieve what I want without knowing the internals of `vue`, but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue the `@` character (in templates) is just a shorthand for `v-on:`. And as petit-vue [should be compatible](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#vue-compatible) in this regard, you can try to use `Attr("v-on:vue:mounted", "mounted()")` instead...